# DOTNET SPA - Connection String is wrong

Tags: c#, ssms, connection-string

I'm doing and DOTNET SPA and I need to configure my ConnectionString, like this :

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=DESKTOP-1QTB41O\SQLEXPRESS; database=vega; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  }
```

But, I'm getting an error :

```
Error: Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '3': '"ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "server=DESKTOP-1QTB41O\SQLEXPRESS; database=vega; Integrated Security=SSPI;"'.
```

Probably because of my backslash. I've tried to put localhost, but I can't connect with localhost on SSMS.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is a DOTNET SPA?

Comment: Dotnet Single Page Application

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Just put a double backslash :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=DESKTOP-1QTB41O\\SQLEXPRESS; database=vega; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  }
```